# Display full date-time, even when the time is 00:00:00

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, date, datetime

I have `date` fields in Oracle tables. When I view the data in the *attribute window*, the dates are displayed like this:

1. `1/1/2017`
2. `1/2/2017 3:50:28 PM`

As demonstrated in #1, ArcMap doesn't show the time portion of the date if it is `00:00:00` (even though it technically exists in the underlying table).

Is there a way to force ArcMap to show the full date-time of date fields in the *attribute table*, even if the time component is `00:00:00`?

Example:

3. `1/1/2017 00:00:00  <<<---`
4. `1/2/2017 3:50:28 PM`

I've poked around the documentation, but haven't found anything specific to this exact issue.

- [Fundamentals of date fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm)
- [Changing the way ArcMap displays short format dates in Windows Vista](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/working-with-date-fields-on-vista.htm)

The reason I ask is:

I'm doing some intensive testing on views based on temporal tables. I'm doing a lot of querying and editing of the time portion of date fields. It would be helpful to see the time portion of the dates, even when the time is `00:00:00`.

Comment: I think you should use python scripting and date package of python for converting the format. I didn't find any documentation about your problem. Maybe it's a limitation of ArcGIS.If you sure that it's a limitation, you can describe this function for esri in ArcGIS Ideas website.I'm sure your problem will solve with python scripting.

Comment: If you are using ArcGIS 10x, you can use arcpy to manipulate and edit data. Also you can use date and time modules and packages of python.

Comment: @wetland Sure, but I don't see how editing the data would help. The dates that don't show time technically have a time component (`00:00:00`). ArcMap simply hides it in the attribute table.

Comment: So, i hope to understand your question. enable time for your layer => layer properies => time and set the time properties. Now you can use time in the date field. To test this feature, add a new date field => field calculator =>select python => select date => select datetime.datetime.now

Comment: It's probably massive overkill for what you are trying to do but you can implement a custom object inspector on the feature class and display the attributes any way you want. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#iobjectinspector.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need this only as a temporal solution for testing purposes you can use [Convert Time Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-time-field.htm) tool to create text field with custom formatting. Every time DATE field is changed you have to rerun this tool.

[image]

As mentioned in [Fundamentals of date fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm):

> Date fields vary between data source types, and their display depends
> on your system locale.
>
> Settings on your Windows system determine how the dates are displayed
> in ArcMap—M/d/yy, MM/dd/yy, yy/MM/dd, and so on. ArcMap uses the
> system short date format (numerical) for displaying dates.

So looks like Windows hide DATE's time when at 00:00:00. And solution may be in [changing windows settings](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/working-with-date-fields-on-windows-7.htm).